What are "EVFTEMPF01" files created by RDI and how to prevent them?
I discovered today the source files "EVFTEMPF01" and "EVFTEMPF02". I was unable to find out what they are and under which circumstances the RDI is creating them. The Files have members with the source code of an SQLRPG Program. So i assume that only complining SQLRPG sources create this file.
The first hit on google when I search "EVFTEMPF01" is a dead link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-are-source-files-evftempf01-and-evftempf02-created
One of the other few hits explains a bit more:
https://code400.com/forum/forum/iseries-programming-languages/sql/144210-why-no-host-variable-with-create-table-with-data
Here they explain, that the precompiler is creating the SQL Source in a QTEMP. But my files EVFTEMP01 was in the Library of where I compiled it. Also they say it gets deleted after it is finished. So I am questioning, if they even mean the same thing.
So I need to know what exactly they are.
Right now I changed the default Parameter OPTION(*EVENTF) from CRTSQLRPGI to OPTION(*NOEVENTF). But this only effects the file
"EVFEVENT" right? I am still not sure if they even related.
EDIT:
First tests show that with *NOEVENTF there are no EVFTEMPF01 Files.
I still would like to know what are those. The code in it is not complete. On the left there are missing some spaces and it is cut off. Probably where the H,F,D,C,O Column is.
I still dont understand whats the file EVFEVENT is for, if the RDI creates the EVFTEMP01 files anyway.
Thank you for the help.
EDIT2: OK now I understand the EVFEVENT File. It contains all messages from the compiling process, like infos and warnings and errors. This is were the RDI gets it for the ERROR LIST. If there is *NOEVENTF in the OPTION Parameter, it will not genereate them. No Error List and you have to check out the spoolfile where the errors happened. Very bad.
But with *EVENTF it creates the EVFTEMP01.
Is there a way to have first one but not the other?

IBM's document comes up for me...

The source files EVFTEMPF01 and EVFTEMPF02 are created when the
OPTION(*EVENT) and RPGPPOPT(*LVL1 or *LVL2) are used in the CRTSQLRPGI
command. These files are used by RPG and the SQL preprocessor when a
compile is done from the RSE (Remote System Explorer) perspective in
WDSC (Websphere® Development Studio client) and RDi (Rational
Developer for System i). These source files can be deleted, once the
programmer is done with their RSE session.

In answer to your last question, no you can't prevent both from being created when compiling SQLRPGLE from RDi.
Not sure why they bother you, they shouldn't ever get big enough to really matter.  But you can always delete them and they will be recreated as needed.

Thank you, your link works for some reason.
The files doesnt bother me, but it bothers my Senior RPG-Developer who still just uses SEU. So he was shocked to find smth unknown to him in his lib and i didnt know what it was and what it was for.

These files are generated when you compile with RDi so that it can show the source with embedded errors, and so that when you click on an error in RDi, it can take you directly to the error in the source. They are important for the proper functioning of RDi, so your other developers should not be deleting them, and if you have multiple developers using RDi, deleting these files while one of them is using RDi, it could cause unexpected results.

IIRC, You can avoid those files by removing the event file generation option from the compile command. When I was developing the compile function for PTC Implementer I had to add the event file options to all the HLL compile commands when the WDSC / RDp / RDi integration was added.
The downside is that RDi compiles won't report errors or warnings if there are any.
